# Does the GoIbibo API work for flights and bus bookings in India?

Tags: air-travel, india, online-resources, bookings, buses

I have been trying to use [GoIbibo API](https://developer.goibibo.com/) for flights and bus bookings in India, but it seems to be broken or maybe they have stopped supporting it. Does anybody know?

Comment: If your trying to book flights and buses from Goibibo, go to [this site](https://www.goibibo.com/). If your trying to use their API for software development, this is not the correct forum for that. Either contact Goibibo directly or post it in some other SE forum.

Comment: This question is not about travel, but software development.